# impart awareness regarding the public's options (how does that apostrophe work?)

Tags: apostrophe

> I want to impart awareness regarding the public's options.

So in this case would public be :

- public's
- publics
- publics'

or something else?

I could just say, "I want to impart awareness regarding options for the public". But I am now curious as to how the apostrophe would work in the original example.

Comment: Is *public* singular here, as in the mass noun referring to all people in a community, or is it a countable sense of *public*, for example in referring to an audience or constituency?

Comment: @choster: I've never seen public pluralized (ignoring software development due to wildly different context and usage). This isn't me saying you're wrong, but rather being surprised that it _can_ actually be pluralized when referring to an audience.

Comment: @Flater The concept of *publics* is mainly used in public relations, marketing, political communications, and related fields. See e.g. Pew, *[U.S. Image Suffers as Publics Around World Question Trump’s Leadership](http://www.pewglobal.org/2017/06/26/u-s-image-suffers-as-publics-around-world-question-trumps-leadership/)*.

Answer (score 1):

The options of the public are the *public's options*.

The rule is simply to add an apostrophe *s* to a plural/collective noun unless it happens to end in *s*

Typical examples are: *men's room*, *women's garments*, *children's toys*. The same would apply to collective nouns like *group* or *assembly*.

If the plural noun ends in an *s*, you normally add just an apostrophe, except in such cases as *the Jones's dogs*, where the pronunciation is the clue.

http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-plural-possessive-nouns.html